# number of contours in contourf function

Tags: matlab, plot

What is the default for the contours in a contourf function in matlab?

For example:

```
Z = peaks(20);
contourf(Z);
```

[image]

What do each of these contours represent? If I don't specify the second term in contourf e.g. contourf(Z,10) which would give 10 contour lines, how does matlab choose the number of contours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the detailed algorithm for calculating the initial contour level step sizes from `MATLABROOT\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\@specgraph\@contourgroup\refresh.m`, around line 25.

Basically, Matlab divides the range into ~10 steps, but adjusts that number a bit depending on the exact value of the range of z-values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default. You are defining the number of contours by using:
Z=peaks(20);
This in effect returns an 20x20 [m,n] matrix of peaks which is stored in Z.

The ranges of the x-axis and y-axis are based on the size of array Z.

The number of contour lines and the values of the contour lines are taken from the minimum and maximum values of peaks inside the Z array.

The Z array is populated with the peaks() function which uses Normal Distribution (or Gaussian distribution).

As the documentation of the 
[contourf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) function says:
 *The number of contour lines and the values of the contour lines are chosen automatically based on the minimum and maximum values of Z. The ranges of the x-axis and y-axis are [1:n] and [1:m], where [m,n] = size(Z).*